# What does the () on a pointer variable means in C

Tags: c, operators

I have a little question:

```
struct point {int x ; int y;};

int main(){

    struct point p = {10,20};

    struct point *pp = &p;

    (∗ pp).x = 10; // what is happening here 

    int y= (∗ pp).y; return 0} // what is happening here
```

and more general , why is the () required?

(its from a tutorial but they got no answer there ..)

Comment: `(∗ pp).x` = `p->x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `.` has higher precedence than `*`. That is, without the parenthesis,

```
*pp.x = 10;
```

stands for

```
*(pp.x) = 10;
```

However, `pp` is a pointer. Thus, the `.` operator does not work on it.
You need to either use `->` operator to access the member of a pointer to struct, or use parenthesis to dereference the pointer before accessing its member.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pointer, like your variable `pp`, you can dereference it by using the dereference operator `*`. It does the opposite of the address-of operator `&`. Foe example:

```
int a = 5;
int *pa = &a;  /* Use address-of operator to get a pointer to `a` */
int b = *pa;   /* Use dereference operator to get the value that `pa` points to */
```

When it comes to structures, normally you use the `->` operator to access member fields of structure pointers, or the `.` operator of non-pointer structures. When you dereference a pointer to a structure, you get the non-pointer version of the structure, and have to use the `.` operator to access the member fields.

The parentheses is because the `.` operator has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`.

Answer (score 2):

As in maths, the parenthesis are used to express priority of operators.

In C, the `.` operator has precedence over the `*` operator. Hence, without the parenthesis, `pp.x` would be interpreted before `*pp` leading to a compilation error. Indeed, `pp` is a pointer and does not have a member variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Both p and pp are pointers ("&" takes the address of) to a type of struct point, not point(s) themselves.

Comment: Order of evaluation has nothing to do with it, don't mix this up with operator precedence. Order of evaluation is concerned about _operands_. Operands in this case: evaluate sub-expression `*pp`, evaluate `(*pp).x`, evaluate `10`. The sub-expression is guaranteed to be evaluated before the expression it is part of. Apart from that, there are no guarantees whether `*pp.x` is evaluated before or after `10`. _That_ is order of evaluation. _Operator precedence_ on the other hand, dictates the order of execution: `()` has higher prio than `.` which has higher prio than `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `point` called `p`, which has x and y coordinates.

Then, you have `pp` which is of type `pointer to a point`. This `pp` points to the *very same* point `p`. So now you have two ways to access your point: `p` (the simple one) and `*pp` (the thing that `pp` points to). It doesn't matter which of these ways you use, you are accessing the same `point`.

There are two operators here: `.` and `*`. Of these, `.` binds more tightly. So the expression `*pp.x` means: first, get the value of `pp.x` and then look what it points to.

But the code wants it the other way round: first, look what `pp` points to and then access the field `x` of that.

The parentheses have the same function as in `(2 + 3) * 5`, which you know from school.